# Долгая компиляция в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build

Компиляция приложений занимает от пяти до десяти минут. Может ли это быть связано с версией Android Studio / Gradle?

Android Studio v.2.1.1
Gradle v.2.10

Конфигурация ПК:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подключи телефон на анероиде к ПК, при первой компиляции выбири свой тел. установить спец. прога в телефон и потом будет копилировать сразу на телефон(телефон должен быть подкл. всегда) .. как раз и проверишь скорость компиляции. У меня не сложный проект пару секунд и все.  Мне кажется логают виртал машины

Comment: В любом случае обновите и студию и грэдл.

Comment: Да, это нормально. Хипстеры в гугле совсем зажрались и считают, что компьютеров кроме и7 с 32 гигами оперативки уже не бывает. Для начала можно попробовать отказаться от Градла.

Comment: @bukkojot человеку, который не может оптимизировать сборку проекта не стоит предлагать отказываться от gradle (а в современном положении вещей такое предложение может понравиться и вовсе только мазахисту)

Comment: 5, а тем более 10 минут - это не нормально, какими бы хипстерами не был наполнен гугл. Первая сборка небольшого приложения около 3 минут (большинство времени на получение и подключение сторонних бибилотек), последующие тестовые запуски 30 - 60 секунд (если опять же не надо что то с инета докачать). Комп у меня corei3, 16 Гб, SSD, не самый хипстерский.
 [Оптимизация и ускорение](https://android.jlelse.eu/faster-android-build-times-a760d274b33c) Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Укажите в gradle.properties такие строчки:

```
org.gradle.parallel=true  #разрешает параллельную обработку в gradle
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M  #задает размер кучи инстанса JVM (здесь 4 гига)
```

В вашей конфигурации мне все нравится кроме строчки: *single channel DDR3*, либо добейте его до 2*8 гигов или разбейте 2*4 гига - вам нужен *dual channel*

И еще работайте на 64-битной JVM: снесите к черту JVM x86 и установите x64